# Html animated content how to

Tags: jquery, css, animation, html5-video, css-sprites

I have a task coming up that requires lively animated screen content just like that example below. Im curious as how this example was done, css, sprite, gif, video? it displays, sliding screens, animated scroll bars, pagination, moving icons etc all timed as a self contained movie. any ideas to how the below is made and to run so efficiently will be greatly appreciated.

http://urban-walks.com/#slides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS using animations. [HubbBlog is a great source for coding information.](http://www.hubbblog.com/html/usingCSS3Animations) https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp W3Schools has a good tutorial about it also. Javascript was also used most likely to sense where the user was at the page.

Comment: Ok thanku, I did think it might be the power of CSS and JavaScript. Seems alot of work for the animated mobile phone screens, which instead a html video would save time. I guess there are pros and cons.

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>

body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    font-size: 25px;

}

@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color: lightgreen; left:-200px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background-color: lightgreen; left:0px; top:0px;}

}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color: lightgreen; left:-200px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background-color: lightgreen; left:0px; top:0px;}
</style>
```

Comment: This answer is lacking an explanation. Doesn't answer the original question.